# Page slider not working On Android, works fine in iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

The code below shows how all the functions are implemented

On iOS everything works fine, the button changes slide, the dots on the bottom change state based on the page and on the last page it displays a signup button,

On Android, the button works only on the first page, the last page doesnt show the signup button, and next button doesnt work on the second page!

```
export default function introScreen({ navigation }) {
const [sliderState, setSliderState] = useState({ currentPage: 0 });
const scrollRef = useRef();
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
const notchSize = StatusBar.currentHeight

const setSliderPage = (event: any) => {
  const { currentPage } = sliderState;
  const { x } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
  const indexOfNextScreen = Math.floor(x / width);
  if (indexOfNextScreen !== currentPage) {
    setSliderState({
      ...sliderState,
      currentPage: indexOfNextScreen,
    });
  }
};
const { currentPage: pageIndex } = sliderState;

const onPressTouch = () => {
  scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({
      x: width*(pageIndex+1),
      animated: true,
  });

}


return (
  <>
    <StatusBar hidden />
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:'black' }}>
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        horizontal={true}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={(event: any) => {
          setSliderPage(event);
        }}
        ref={scrollRef}
      >
            <View style={{ width, height, alignItems: 'center', }}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/images/Intorduction/1.png')} style={styles.imageStyle}  />
                <BlurView tint={'dark'} intensity={70} style={{width:'80%',borderRadius:10, marginTop:10}}>
                  <Text style={[styles.textStyle,{color:'rgb(255, 190, 46)'}]}bla bla</Text>
                </BlurView>
            </View>

            <View style={{ width, height, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/images/Intorduction/2.png')} style={styles.imageStyle} />
                <BlurView tint={'dark'} intensity={70} style={{width:'80%',borderRadius:10, marginTop:10}}>
                  <Text style={[styles.textStyle,{color:'rgb(255, 190, 46)'}]}>bla bla</Text>
                </BlurView>
            </View>

            <View style={{ width, height, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/images/Intorduction/3.png')} style={styles.imageStyle} />
                <BlurView tint={'light'} intensity={70} style={{width:'80%',borderRadius:10, marginTop:10}}>
                  <Text style={[styles.textStyle,{color:'rgb(241, 250, 238)'}]}>bla bla</Text>
                </BlurView>
            </View>
      </ScrollView>

        {pageIndex != 2 ? 
        <View style={styles.paginationWrapper}>
          {Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map((key, index) => (
            <View style={[styles.paginationDots, { opacity: pageIndex === index ? 1 : 0.2 }]} key={index} />
          ))}
        </View>
        :
        <></>
        }
        {pageIndex != 2 ? 
        <BlurView tint={'dark'} intensity={70} style={styles.nextButton}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}} onPress={onPressTouch} >
              <Text style={{color:'rgb(241, 250, 238)',fontFamily: 'poiret-one', fontSize:25}}>
                Next
              </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </BlurView>
        :
        <BlurView tint={'light'} intensity={70} style={styles.signUpButton}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}} onPress={() =>navigation.navigate('Login')} >
            <Text style={{color:'black',fontFamily: 'poiret-one', fontSize:25}}>
              Sign Up
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </BlurView>
        }
    </SafeAreaView>
  </>
);
}
```

Comment: The issue comes from SafeAreaView. If you remove it, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have narrowed down the problem to the width and the 'event.nativeEvent.contentOffset', the returning number is close to 1 but it is (0.9), therefor math.floor was giving 0 as the index number,

I have changed Math.floor to Math.round and it is working perfectly fine,

If anyone wants a Introduction Slider for their app they can use this